# Показ времени работы процесса из БД php

Tags: php, время

Не могу никак сообразить.

В общем есть таблица в бд вида:

[image: Таблица в БД]

В ней логируется запуск, пауза, остановка процесса.

Хотелось бы узнать как мне посчитать время работы процесса, т.е. работа процесса это состояние 1, стоп и пауза это 2 и 0

Как узнать общее время работы процесса в виде 0:00:00:00 (дни:часы:минуты:секунды)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Общее время работы скрипта это сумма периодов от старта до паузы (остановки). Чтобы подсчитать это - выбираем все записи из БД для заданого процесса отсортированные по времени в порядке возрастания. А дальше простенький скрипт:

```
$worked = 0;
$in_process = false;
$start = time();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    switch ($row['event']) {
        case 1:
            $start = $row['timestamp'];
            $in_process = true;
            break;
        defaut:
            $worked += $row['timestamp'] - $start;
            $in_process = false;
    }
}

if ($in_process) { // если скрипт сейчас в работе
    $worked += $time - $start; // учитываем время от последнего запуска до текущего времени
}
echo "Worked time in seconds: " . $worked;
```

Comment: А как из этого получить дни:часы:минуты:секунды ???

Comment: Вот готовый ответ на ваш вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273804/convert-seconds-into-days-hours-minutes-and-seconds

Comment: Спасибо большое! :)

Comment: А можете еще подсказать, у меня постоянно начинается отсчет с нуля и только если есть еще одна запись с timestamp то начинает вроде считать правильно, а мне надо учитывать в реальном времени

Comment: То есть и те процессы которые еще выполняются?

Comment: Исправил ответ с учетом случая, что процесс может еще работать